# How to get to design view on Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, design-view

This is driving me insane. I keep clicking on the form I want to see but it just keeps showing me the code for it as oppose to the actual form. I'm on Visual Basic on visual studio if that helps.

Comment: Right click and choose `View Designer`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137556/how-do-i-open-a-visual-studio-project-in-design-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the FormName.vb in the file view list and hit View Designer...

Answer (score 1):

At the solution explorer, right click on the file and select open with then select -Web Forms Editor- you can set it as default if you want. 
To see the code, right click on the file and select -View Mark Up - 
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

With WinForms I had the same trouble, it turns out that VS2013 defaults to the "Class View" by default, so be sure to select the "Solution Explorer" first, then you can just double click the form name and the form designer for the form should open.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable HTML Designer you can access this setting under Tools menu,

Tools > Options > HTML Designer > General

Make sure **Enable HTML designer** option is checked. You can also select how you want to see your forms on start up.

- Source View
- Design View
- Split View

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the web designer, there is a setting under Tools->Options->Html Designer->General called "Start Pages In" that lets you choose design or code or split view

If you are talking about Silverlight/XAML, there is a setting under Tools->Options->Text Editor->XAML called "Default View" that lets you choose to always open documents in full xaml view

Answer (score 0):

WinForms? Double click on the Form name in Solution Explorer always worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

right click your project (right below the solution) in the solution explorer, add existing item, go to where you saved your project and add the form, and double click on the form. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click any HTML file in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and click on Open with
   2.Select the HTML (web forms) editor
   3.Click on Set as default
   4.Click on the OK button