# C# - windows form applications - saving a file

Tags: c#, winforms, file, save

That will be super idiot question, but I don't usually write in Visual studio and C#...

The question is:
how do i save files while making the gui applications in "windows form application" ? I mean, how to save it and  send it to someone and he will be able to open it and the code & designer thing will be visible?

Normally, when did the console applications it was no problem - just saving the .cs... But now - when i save it, i get milion of files, and none of them shows me the designer thing, but only the code...?

Comment: Do you mean the `*.Designer.cs` files?

Comment: If all you need is to open up the designer, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17137556/2316200), there's no special procedure to save a winform project.

Comment: Just saved a file with a eur>pln converter with gui etc. all working and now when I do the f7 thing I get a strange new code, not the designer where I place the buttons etc. - maybe you didn't get my point or it's just me being so stupid...
Also, when opened again the file that I just wrote with the converter working, when I compile it, it gives me an empty GUI.... No buttons etc. that were in the converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is zip up the source files with the .sln. He unzips on his side, double clicks the .sln file and all done.

[image: folder structure]

In the above image you can see, a solution file along with the projects in their respective folders. You just zip up the folders with the .sln (solution file) and all done.

Comment: Wow, that's it :) Thank you so much, now I get it. The file I was looking for was the .sln not the .cs etc stupid me.

Comment: No worries, once you know it - you never forget it :) Good luck with your c# and stackoverflow endeavors. Also don't forget to mark this as your answer.