# How to open Designer View in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, designer

I got a project source codes developed by Visual C# 2012. I opened & built it without any problem.
Then, I would like to open its visual portions; such as forms, buttons, ... I clicked "View" menu, I found the menu items are 'Code', "Solution Explorer", "Team Explorer", "Server Explorer", ... The item 'Designer' is missing. How come? How can I open 'Designer' view window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I open a Visual Studio project in design view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137556/how-do-i-open-a-visual-studio-project-in-design-view)

Comment: Yes, very close. Sorry for not studying it very carefully before posting it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The designer view is only available for some classes. Those that have any graphical representation to be displayed, such as

- form and user control in WinForms
- window, page or user control in WPF
- view in ASP.NET

In case of these components the designer is available from the context menu in Solution Explorer. So open the solution explorer (View -> Solution Explorer, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>). Select one of the mentioned classes like form or user control. Right-click it and from the context menu select View Designer (or simply <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>). That will move you to the designer view.

Comment: Great, it works and the 'Designer' item appears under 'View' again.

Comment: BTW, per you said "Select one of the mentioned classes like form or user control", how can I easily to find all files which are forms or user controls because all file extensions are .cs and it's very inefficient to open it one by one?

Comment: In Visual Studio they have different icons