# Windows Form Toolbox is empty

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In my Visual Studio 2015, Windows Forms Tool Box (where we have controls like Text box, button etc) is not showing up.

I tried checking all the check marks in Views->ToolBars, but no use.

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you have opened a Windows Forms project.

Open `View` menu and check `Toolbox` or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> shortcut and you will see the toolbox.

The toolbox will fill with controls when you open a `Form` or `UserControl` in **design view**.

Comment: it dose not open the control when loading form designer

Comment: How to open a project in design view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137556/how-do-i-open-a-visual-studio-project-in-design-view